# The google authentication page is not redirecting after the authentication using OAuth2.0

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am setting up a spring security using OAuth2.0 using spring boot application. The authentication page is coming with already logged in google user but after selecting one it is again loading the same authentication page.

HomeController.java

```
import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
public class HomeController {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        System.out.println("inside home");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView loginPage() {
        System.out.println("inside login");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping("user")
    @ResponseBody
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("inside userrrrrrrrr");
        return principal;
    }
}
```

AppSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity  
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

       // System.out.println(httpSecurity.);
        try {
            System.out.println("inside configure");
            httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().disable();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("exception caught:"+e);
        }   

    }
}
```

This is my application.properties file for the OAuth configuration :
I am changing client-id and client-secret code.

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id = 434559791042-642qk4agcs32g1rajsssss62ilrd86s4.apps.googleusercontent.com
security.oauth2.client.client-secret = 1l4jqw7lBailpuVgWobvcxwo 
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
security.oauth2.client.tokenName = oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authenticationScheme = query
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme = form
security.oauth2.client.scope = profile email

security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri = https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo = false
```

in my google api app i have given below redirects .

Authorised JavaScript origins : http://localhost:8080
Authorised redirect URIs: http://localhost:8080/login

The google authentication frame is coming with my already logged in account but when i am selecting it, again it is showing the same authentication frame.
It should be redirecting to my native app after authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Check the redirect_uri Spring is sending to Google.
You can do this in your browsers by right clicking and selecting inspect, then select the network tab.
So when you select sign in to google in your webapp, you should see spring send a redirect response to your browser, it will be to Google, and it will include a parameter redirect_uri, this is were Google will send the redirect to. Make sure it is correct.
And make sure it matches the URI you provided Google in the API page, as Google 
will block any it doesn't know about.

Comment: this is i see in the auth request when i try to login with google account. redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login
Authorised redirect URIs value in google api page : http://localhost:8080/login

i have api created in my controller with request mapping as "/login". So ideally the call should come here but its not working.

Comment: Your redirect_uri above seems to be missing the protocol: i.e. http or https, I believe this is required by Google.

Comment: The redirect url was actually http://localhost:8080/login. I forgot to add that in the comment section. So my redirect url is actually "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=434559791042-642qk4agcs32g1rajdmoit62ilrd86s4.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=profile%20email&state=wnaMPe"  and  Authorised redirect URIs is "http://localhost:8080/login". Do you see anything wrong in this?

Comment: i have implement openid connect in spring. when i call api it does not redirect to authentication it just gives null pointer exception. can you please help